# KDE headset mic not working

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, microphone, headset

Recently I bought a new headset and it works perfectly on my phone but in my KUBUNTU desktop doesn't work. The audio output is great but its mic is not working while my other headphone's mic works in it. I tried a lot of ways but nothing changed.

it's kubuntu 21.04 with kde plasma. And the mic is attched directly to headset and it works fine with my mobile phone

I'd be happy if you help me. Thanks

Comment: What version of the OS? How is the mic attached? What does I have tried a lot of ways mean, give details.

Comment: it's kubuntu 21.04 with kde plasma. And the mic is attched directly to headset and it works fine with my mobile phone

Comment: Lets try again how is it connected to the COMPUTER? USB, Bluetooth etc.

Comment: It has AUX and USB. I use AUX. USB just turns off the lights of it and nothing else.